# Выполнить подсчёт всех символов "а" в файле

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
F = open('file.txt', 'r')
kolvo = 0
for i in F:
  if 'a' in i:
    kolvo =+1
  if kolvo > 1:
    print('Количество элементов в файле :', kolvo)
  elif kolvo == 0:
    print('Элементов в файле нет')
```

В данном коде требуется прочитать все строки файла и выполнить подсчёт всех символов "а" в файле. Но у меня в любом случае программа выдаёт "Элементов в файле нет". Помогите исправить. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: У вас поплыло редактирование текста? Или вы действительно написали весь код "в столбик"?

Comment: исправьте отступы

Comment: и надо `+=`, а не `=+`

Answer (score 3):

Открывать файлы лучше с помощью контекстного менеджера `with`, это гарантия того, что файл будет закрыт после выполнения действий.

В питоне есть оператор `+=` и нет оператора `=+`.

Когда вы пишете `x =+1`, вы на самом деле пишете `x = 1`. Поскольку у вас неправильно написано условие, у вас не срабатывает ни один блок. Потому что у вас в условии `kolvo > 1`, но у вас оно не `> 1`, а просто 1. Нужно было делать условие больше или равно. `kolvo >= 1`.

Но т.к. 0 - это falsy-объект, а все что больше 0 - это truthy объект, то можно вообще не писать эти сравнения, а написать так, как в моем примере.

```py
count = 0

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        if 'a' in row:
            count += 1

if count:
    print(f'Количество элементов в файле: {count}')
else:
    print('Элементов в файле нет')
```

Если вы хотите посчитать не количество строк с вашей буковой, а именно количество символа в файле, то это еще проще:

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    count = f.read().count('a')

if count:
    print(f'Количество элементов в файле: {count}')
else:
    print('Элементов в файле нет')
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Но почему-то всё равно в IDLE выдаёт постоянно "Элементов в файле нет", хотя в файле они есть

Comment: @Ivan Pavlov Скопируйте код из примера и запустите именно его. Я там допустил неточность, но уже исправил. Все работает.

Comment: @Ivan Pavlov если не работает, убедитесь, что вы открываете в коде тот файл. Он должен лежат в одной директории со скриптом. И убедитесь, что буквы `a` в файле на латинице.

Comment: Неточность заметил сразу и исправил. Буквы на латинице, директория одна и та же, но всё равно результат 1(

Comment: Недостаточно просто открыть файл, надо из него еще прочитать.

Comment: @Эникейщик в данном случае итератор позволяет ничего не читать

Comment: @IvanPavlov а вот кстати интересно, вы хотите посчитать количество букв а или количество строк, в которых есть буквы а? Потому что по вашему коду я решил, что вы хотте посчитать количество строк, в которых есть буква а

Comment: Количество букв а

Comment: @IvanPavlov а судя по вашему коду, вы считаете именно строки, в которых есть буквы а. Посмотрите мой ответ еще раз, я добавил еще один вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Залезу и я со своим вариантом:

```
kolvo = open('file.txt').read().count('a')
if kolvo:
    print(f'Количество элементов в файле: {kolvo}')
else:
    print('Элементов в файле нет')
```

Answer (score -1):

Выражение: kolvo =+ 1, вот корень зла. Нужно писать +=.
Нет острой необходимости писать:

```
if kolvo > 1:

    print('Количество элементов в файле :', kolvo)

elif kolvo == 0:

    print('Элементов в файле нет')
```

Можно просто написать:

```
 print('Количество элементов в файле :', kolvo)
```